# Smaller Changesets when Generating Changelogs

Tags: liquibase

**Is it possible to generate change logs, merging change sets together?**

Like this:

```
<changeSet author="Author" id="1">
    <dropNotNullConstraint columnDataType="varchar(255)" columnName="name" tableName="table"/>
    <dropNotNullConstraint columnDataType="varchar(255)" columnName="phone" tableName="table"/>
    <dropNotNullConstraint columnDataType="bigint" columnName="email" tableName="table"/>
</changeSet>
```

instead of this:

```
<changeSet author="Author" id="1">
    <dropNotNullConstraint columnDataType="varchar(255)" columnName="name" tableName="table"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="Author" id="2">
    <dropNotNullConstraint columnDataType="varchar(255)" columnName="phone" tableName="table"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="Author" id="3">
    <dropNotNullConstraint columnDataType="bigint" columnName="email" tableName="table"/>
</changeSet>
```

If so, can you choose a custom scope? (*e.g.* all changes in a given table are grouped together, *etc.*). If not, is there a 'best practice' reason for avoiding grouping them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean command [generateChangeLog](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html) then no, there is no option to put all changes in one `changeLog`. However you can create that programatically if you need.

Liquibase should changes per `changeSet` because each `changeSet` **is executed in one transaction** [read here](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html). So if you include a lot of changes inside one `changeSet` and execution of that `changeSet` fails, it would be harder for you to find on which change it failed. It's better to handle change per `changeSet`.

**note:** sometimes I'm also using multiple changes per `changeSet` (for example remarks (comments) for table or DML (data) modifications) but I prefer to have one DDL per changeSet.

Comment: bilak, I meant in the `diff` command. Thank you for your answer, it does seem like there is no way of doing that. I think that when modifying a table to add a few columns, it would be nice to be able to group those automatically. When you say "however you can create that programmatically," do you mean by creating some kind of liquibase plugin?

Comment: Yes I mean create liquibase plugin or create your own extension.